# What is the best solution to perform scheduled tasks in Java, whatever the OS?

Tags: java, service, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to generate alarms on my Java desktop application :

- alarms set with a specific date/time which can be in 5 minutes or 5 months
- I need to be able to create a SWT application when the alarm is triggered
- I need this to be able to work on any OS. The software users will likely have Windows (90% of them), and the rest Mac OS (including me)
- the software license must allow me to use it in a commercial program, without requiring to open source it (hence, no GPL)
- I cannot require the users to install Cygwin, so the implementation needs to be native to Windows and Unix

I am developing using Java, Eclipse, SWT and my application is deployed from my server using Java Web Start. I'm using Mac OS X.6 for developing.

---

I think I have a few options:

1. Run my application at startup, and handle everything myself;
2. Use a system service.
3. Use the cron table on Unix, and Scheduled Tasks on Windows

---

## Run at startup

I don't really like this solution, I'm hoping for something more elegant.
Refs: [I would like to run my Java program on System Startup on Mac OS/Windows. How can I do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949649/i-would-like-to-run-my-java-program-on-system-startup-on-mac-os-windows-how-can)

## System service

If I run it as a system service, I can benefit from this, because the OS will ensure that my software:

- is always running
- doesn't have/need a GUI
- restarts on failure

I've researched some resources that I can use:

- [run4j](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) — CPL — runs on Windows only, seems like a valid candidate
- [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html) — Apache 2.0 — Unix only, seems like a valid candidate
- [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/licenseOverview.html) — Various — I cannot afford paid licenses, and the free one is a GPL. Hence, I don't want to/can't use this

My questions in the system service options are:

1. Are there other options?
2. Is my planned implementation correct:

   - at the application startup, check for existence of the service
   - if it is not installed:

     - escalate the user to install the service (root on Unix, UAC on Windows)
     - if the host OS is Windows, use run4j to register the service
     - if the host OS is Unix, use jsvc to register the service
   - if it is not running, start it

Thus, at the first run, the application will install the service and start it. When the application closes the service is still running and won't need the application ever again, except if it is unregistered.
However, I think I still miss the "run on startup" feature.

Am I right? Am I missing something?

## cron / Task Scheduler

On Unix, I can easily use the cron table without needing the application to escalate the user to root. I don't need to handle restarts, system date changes, etc. Seems nice.

On Windows, I can use the [Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569), even in command-line using [At](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx) or [SchTasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx). This seems nice, but I need this to be compatible from XP up to 7, and I can't easily test this.

---

So what would you do? Did I miss something? Do you have any advice that could help me pick the best and most elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up implementing:

```
public class AlarmManager {
    public static final String ALARM_CLI_FORMAT = "startalarm:";
    public static SupportedOS currentOS = SupportedOS.UNSUPPORTED_OS;

    public enum SupportedOS {
        UNSUPPORTED_OS,
        MAC_OS,
        WINDOWS,
    }

    public AlarmManager() {
        final String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        if (osName == null) {
            L.e("Unable to retrieve OS!");
        } else if ("Mac OS X".equals(osName)) {
            currentOS = SupportedOS.MAC_OS;
        } else if (osName.contains("Windows")) {
            currentOS = SupportedOS.WINDOWS;
        } else {
            L.e("Unsupported OS: "+osName);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Windows only: name of the scheduled task
     */
    private String getAlarmName(final long alarmId) {
        return new StringBuilder("My_Alarm_").append(alarmId).toString();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the command line to trigger an alarm
     * @param alarmId
     * @return
     */
    private String getAlarmCommandLine(final long alarmId) {
        return new StringBuilder("javaws -open ").append(ALARM_CLI_FORMAT).append(alarmId).append(" ").append(G.JNLP_URL).toString();
    }

    /**
     * Adds an alarm to the system list of scheduled tasks
     * @param when
     */
    public void createAlarm(final Calendar when) {
        // Create alarm
        // ... stuff here
        final long alarmId = 42;

        // Schedule alarm
        String[] commandLine;
        Process child;
        final String alarmCL = getAlarmCommandLine(alarmId);
        try {
            switch (currentOS) {
            case MAC_OS:
                final String cron = new SimpleDateFormat("mm HH d M '*' ").format(when.getTime()) + alarmCL;

                commandLine = new String[] {
                        "/bin/sh", "-c",
                        "crontab -l | (cat; echo \"" + cron + "\") | crontab"
                };
                child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
                break;

            case WINDOWS:
                commandLine = new String[] {
                        "schtasks",
                        "/Create",
                        "/ST "+when.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + when.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        "/SC ONCE",
                        "/SD "+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(when.getTime()), // careful with locale here! dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy? I'm French! :)
                        "/TR \""+alarmCL+"\"",
                        "/TN \""+getAlarmName(alarmId)+"\"",
                        "/F",
                };
                L.d("create command: "+Util.join(commandLine, " "));
                child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
                break;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            L.e("Unable to schedule alarm #"+alarmId, e);
            return;
        }

        L.i("Created alarm #"+alarmId);
    }

    /**
     * Removes an alarm from the system list of scheduled tasks
     * @param alarmId
     */
    public void removeAlarm(final long alarmId) {
        L.i("Removing alarm #"+alarmId);
        String[] commandLine;
        Process child;
        try {
            switch (currentOS) {
            case MAC_OS:
                commandLine = new String[] {
                        "/bin/sh", "-c",
                        "crontab -l | (grep -v \""+ALARM_CLI_FORMAT+"\") | crontab"
                };
                child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
                break;

            case WINDOWS:
                commandLine = new String[] {
                        "schtasks",
                        "/Delete",
                        "/TN \""+getAlarmName(alarmId)+"\"",
                        "/F",
                };
                child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
                break;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            L.e("Unable to remove alarm #"+alarmId, e);
        }
    }

    public void triggerAlarm(final long alarmId) {
        // Do stuff
        //...
        L.i("Hi! I'm alarm #"+alarmId);

        // Remove alarm
        removeAlarm(alarmId);
    }
}
```

Usage is simple. Schedule a new alarm using:

```
final AlarmManager m = new AlarmManager();
final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
m.createAlarm(cal);
```

Trigger an alarm like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    if (args.length >= 2 && args[1] != null && args[1].contains(AlarmManager.ALARM_CLI_FORMAT)) {
        try {
            final long alarmId = Long.parseLong(args[1].replace(AlarmManager.ALARM_CLI_FORMAT, ""));
            final AlarmManager m = new AlarmManager();
            m.triggerAlarm(alarmId);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            L.e("Unable to parse alarm !", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on Mac OS X.6 and Windows Vista. The class `L` is an helper to `System.out.println` and `G` holds my global constants (here, my JNLP file on my server used to launch my application).

Answer (score 3):

Bicou: Great that you shared your solution!

Note that the "schtasks.exe" has some localization issues, if you want to create a daily trigger with it, on an English Windows you'd have to use "daily", on a German one (for example) you'd have to use "täglich" instead.

To resolve this issue I've implemented the call to `schtasks.exe` with the `/xml`-option, providing a temporary xml-file which I create by template.

The easiest way to create such a template is to create a task "by hand" and use the "export"-function in the task management GUI tool.

Answer (score 2):

Of the available options you have listed, IMHO Option 3 is better.
As you are looking only for an external trigger to execute the application, CRON or Scheduled tasks are better solutions than other options you have listed. By this way, you remove a complexity from your application and also your application need not be running always. It could be triggered externally and when the execution is over, your application will stop. Hence, unnecessary resource consumption is avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using Quartz http://quartz-scheduler.org/ . It has a CRON like syntax to schedule jobs.

Comment: The thing I like about cron on unix is that it's already installed and doesn't require root privileges. Quartz seems nice if I can use a cron-like syntax, however I don't want my users to install extra software just to run mine (same for running cygwin).

Comment: Well, it can certainly make your life easier, and it doesn't require much exra JARs.

Comment: Oh wait, I misread the description of the product. It looks really nice! I'll have a closer look throughout the day and I'll try it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I still need to find a way to launch automatically at startup an empty program that will start the Quartz scheduler, which jobs will actually run when I need them to. So Quartz solves the alarm/scheduling part, but not the actual background process management. This still requires the user to launch my program in the first place, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also, if your application/service with Quartz isn't running when a trigger should occur according to your cron-like scheduler expression, you will miss the event.

Comment: OK, so my problem is only half-solved with Quartz. I'd need to use solution #1 in my post to start the scheduler, which may be killed randomly by the user or the system (low memory, crash, etc.). That's not as reliable as I wish my program would be.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, but that possibility is always present. You can't really avoid the user killing your process, or the OS terminating it in extreme cases.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15169/discussion-between-bicou-and-adam-l-monos)

Comment: Dear All, I am also having the same problem. I am using Quartz and it's awesome but still need I need to find a way that on every windows start up my Quartz will shoot and start it's scheduling job. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your scenario is correct. Since services are system specific things, IMHO you should not user a generic package to cover them all, but have a specific mechanism for every system.